# Reference for Smooth Action of Compact Lie Group on Manifolds

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

I am looking for a good reference (textbook, lecture notes, etc) for the theory on smooth actions of compact Lie groups on manifolds. In particular, I am interested in the Slice Theorem and its consequences. Ideally (but not necessary), it should be self-contained and focus on the simpler case of compact Lie groups rather than the more general case.

There have been several other questions already posted here asking for references for the Slice Theorem, however most of them are unanswered. The one recommendation that I have found is "The Topology of Torus Actions on Symplectic Manifolds" by Audin. However, it only covers Lie group actions in the first chapter and it is not very self-contained. I was wondering if anyone had a recommendation for a more in-depth and self-contained treatment of this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard reference I know is:

*Bredon, Glen E.*, Introduction to compact transformation groups, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 46. New York-London: Academic Press. XIII,459 p. (1972). [ZBL0246.57017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.57017).

Another reference is

*Koszul, J. L.*, Lectures on groups of transformations. Notes by R. R. Simha and R. Sridharan, Tata Institute of Fundamental Research Lectures on Mathematics and Physics. Mathematics. 32. Bombay: Tata Institute of Fundamental Research. 97 p. (1965). [ZBL0195.04605](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0195.04605).

freely available [here](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr32.pdf). See the proof of the slice theorem for proper actions (which is more general than actions of compact groups) in Theorem 1 in in Chapter II.4.  Actually, I like Koszul's lectures quite a bit since he covers useful material on group actions which is hard to find elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a look at that textbook and it seems to cover the general theory well. However, I could not find a reference for the Slice theorem in that textbook. At an initial glance I had assumed it would be in the section on Tubes and Slices in chapter 2 but it does not seem to be there. Could you please let me know where the Slice theorem appears in the textbook?

Comment: @Nanoputian: Unfortunately, Bredon does not state things very clearly here. First of all, the action of a compact Lie group $G$ on a (smooth) manifold $M$ is linearizable: There exists an equivariant embedding of $M$ in some $R^n$ such that $G$ has a representation as a subgroup of $O(n)$. Then you look at Lemma 5.1 and Corollary 5.2 in Bredon's book and see that not only they give you a tube, but also a slice. Bredon treats the problem as a topologist. As a differential geometer, in the context of smooth actions of compact groups, instead of using linearizations, I'd simply say:

Comment: Put a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $M$. Given an orbit $N=Gx\subset M$, consider the orthogonal complement $N\subset T_xM$ to $T_xGx$ and apply the exponential map to $N$. The image of a small ball around zero in $N$ will be a slice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and extra reference. I will check out the lecture notes. That also seems quite useful.