# If a finite group $G$ act on a orientable closed surface $X$ preserving orientation, then is $X/G$ a closed surface?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Since the finite group must act on $X$ discontinuously, the quotient space $X/G$ should be an orbifold, and it seems that the 2 dimensional orbifolds are all homeomorphic to manifolds with boundaries. If the group action does not preserve orientation of the surface, like a reflection, then a boundary will occur in the quotient space $X/G$. Will this also happen in the orientation preserving case?

I tried to show that a finite order orientation preserving automorphism only have finitely many fixed points, but I do not know whether there is counter example. If this is true, then every fixed point will result in a cone point rather than a boundary point in the orbifold $X/G$.

Comment: I won't have time to write a full answer until later, but it is true that there are only finitely many fixed points, at least if the manifold is connected and the action is non-trivial.  The key is that the fixed point set is a disjoint union of closed submanifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in the smooth category, the result is easy (if you know some basic differential geometry). In the topological category, this is actually a nontrivial theorem, essentially due to Kerékjártó. You can find a modern proof of the Kerékjártó theorem in

*Constantin, Adrian; Kolev, Boris*, [**The theorem of Kerékjártó on periodic homeomorphisms of the disc and the sphere**](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303256), Enseign. Math., II. Sér. 40, No. 3-4, 193-204 (1994). [ZBL0852.57012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0852.57012).

The paper is freely available on arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303256.pdf).  The reduction from a theorem about periodic homeomorphisms of the sphere and the plane to the case of surfaces takes a bit of thought, you can use, for instance, Proposition 2.4 in the linked paper and the main theorem to prove:

Suppose that $S$ is a topological surface (compactness is irrelevant), $f: S\to S$ is a periodic homeomorphism and $x\in S$ is a fixed point of $f$. Then there is an open disk neighborhood $U$ of $x$ invariant under $f$ such that the restriction  of $f$ to $U$ is topologically conjugate to a rotation or a reflection acting on the plane.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me a hint about the smooth category case? Do I need to proof the analogy of Kerékjártó's theorem? Since you mentioned differential geometry, I guess introducing a metric will help, but I do not come up with how it works.

Comment: @qdmj: It is very general: If $G$ is a compact Lie group acting smoothly on a manifold $M$ with a fixed point $x$, then the action of $G$ is locally linearizable at $x$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604610/reference-for-smooth-action-of-compact-lie-group-on-manifolds).

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit confused. Why is it relavent to Lie group as I am considering a finite group $G$?

Comment: @qdmj every finite group is a Lie group